# Constructing a new column with multi-condition in pandas & numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I have been trying for hours to do simple multi-condition in pandas but I am facing errors and cannot achieve what I want although I feel it is pretty simple!

I have this df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Christine'],

                   'country': ['US', 'UK', 'CA'],
                   'Age': [10,20,40]})

df1
```

looks like:

```
    name        country     Age
0   Sara             US     10
1   John             UK     20
2   Christine        CA     40
```

I want to achieve multi-condition like if the `Age is > 10` and country is in allowed list of countries a result will appear in a new column.

What I did:

I tried to use `np.where` but I got an error  `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I also tried to use `np.logical_and` , the same error was thrown, tried to use apply & lambda but also no success.

```
allowed_countries = ['UK','India','Germany']


conditions  = [np.logical_and(df1['Age'] >= 10 , df1['country'] in allowed_countries), np.logical_and((df1['Age'] >= 10), (df1['country'] == 'CA'))]
choices     = [ "Allowed", 'Partially allowed']


df1['admission'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

My original df has 50K rows so I am looking for the most efficient way. Thanks

Comment: I also suggested using an array to see if this helps - see the answer update.  Over a larger dataset it may help.

Comment: @MDR Thank you, it works perfectly with `np.array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe...

```
df1['country'].isin(allowed_countries)
```

So...

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Christine'],

                   'country': ['US', 'UK', 'CA'],
                   'Age': [10,20,40]})

allowed_countries = ['UK','India','Germany']


conditions  = [np.logical_and(df1['Age'] >= 10 , df1['country'].isin(allowed_countries)), np.logical_and((df1['Age'] >= 10), (df1['country'] == 'CA'))]
choices     = [ "Allowed", 'Partially allowed']


df1['admission'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

**Output of df1:**

```
    name       country  Age     admission
0   Sara       US       10      nan
1   John       UK       20      Allowed
2   Christine  CA       40      Partially allowed
```

**Additional:**

For a tweak in speed maybe try:

```
allowed_countries = np.array(['UK','India','Germany'])
```

Compared to the list for the example data:

```
list:       2.12 ms ± 128 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
np.array:   2.08 ms ± 85.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```